# Raspberry Pi - Node.js run Python script to continuously sample ADC

Tags: python, node.js, socket.io, raspberry-pi

I am trying to host a local server (using Node.js) on a Raspberry Pi.  The Pi has an ADC (MCP3008) connected to it, and I have a Python script that continuously samples the ADC and prints the current value.  I want to have the Node server run the Python script, and whenever it sees a print statement, to just do a console.log(current value) for the time being.  I am new to Node and web development in general, so it may be something simple that I'm missing so that Node will continuously receive data from the Python script.  I'm trying to use Socket.io at the moment, as that seems to make sense as the method for Node to see changes from the Python script, but maybe this isn't the best way to do it.  The basic webpage is from a tutorial I found (http://www.jaredwolff.com/blog/raspberry-pi-getting-interactive-with-your-server-using-websockets/).  The code I am currently using is here:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
  , url= require('url')
  , fs = require('fs')
  , gpio = require('onoff').Gpio
  , PythonShell = require('python-shell');

app.listen(5000);

function handler (req, res) {

    var path = url.parse(req.url).pathname;

    if (path == '/') {
        index = fs.readFile(__dirname+'/public/index.html', 
            function(error,data) {

                if (error) {
                    res.writeHead(500);
                    return res.end("Error: unable to load index.html");
                }

                res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
                res.end(data);
            });
    } else if( /\.(js)$/.test(path) ) {
        index = fs.readFile(__dirname+'/public'+path, 
            function(error,data) {

                if (error) {
                    res.writeHead(500);
                    return res.end("Error: unable to load " + path);
                }

                res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
                res.end(data);
            });
    } else {
        res.writeHead(404);
        res.end("Error: 404 - File not found.");
    }
}

// Python
var pyshell = new PythonShell('mcp3008.py');

pyshell.run('mcp3008.py', function (err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Results: %j', results);
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    pyshell.on('message', function (message) {
        console.log(message);
    });
});
```

Thank you for any hints or help that you can provide!

Comment: Why not just code the ADC access in node.js rather than do this cross language stuff?  You can likely find some existing code to start with.

Answer (score 1):

As jfriend00 recommended, I looked into node.js solutions.  I had previously tried this, using several mcp3008 packages available on npm, but none of them successfully installed on my Raspberry Pi (model B).  However, I ended up rewriting the one located here (https://github.com/fiskeben/mcp3008.js) as a separate .js file, included it with my code (along with some work from the npm spi library), and put it into a loop to read the ADC pin.  That's working for now, and should be good enough for my current needs, but it still seems like a more processor-intensive solution than it should be.  Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Thanks Justin, your script worked perfectly and solved a major headache allowing me to do all the ADC checking and socket emits to a remote server in Node.